# Concat rows using parent ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to concat to rows if the other row has a reference to the parent ID?

Here's my example:

```
+----+--------+-----------+
| Id | Title  | ParentID  |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  1 | AAAAAA | NULL      |
|  2 | BBBBBB | NULL      |
|  3 | CCCCCC | 1         |
|  4 | DDDDDD | 2         |
+----+--------+-----------+
```

Expected output will be

```
+----+--------------+
| Id | Title        | 
+----+--------------+
|  1 | AAAAAACCCCCC |  
|  2 | BBBBBBDDDDDD |
+----+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use self join with id = parentID. From this result concatenate both the title columns.

For example:

```
select 
    A.id, A.title || B.title as title 
from 
    (select * from table) A 
inner join 
    (select * from table) B on A.id = B.parentID
```

Comment: @Khen . . . (1) This is not valid SQL Server code, so it is baffling why you would accept this.  (2) Unnecessary subqueries in the `FROM` clause just clutter the query (and affect performance in some databases).  This is not a good answer and it doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
create table test(id int, title varchar(10), ParentId Int);

insert into test (id, title, ParentId) Values (1, 'AAAAAA', null), (2, 'BBBBBB', null), (3, 'CCCCCC', 1), (4, 'DDDDDD', 2);

SELECT T1.Id, T1.title + '' + T2.title
FROM test T1
INNER JOIN test T2 ON T1.Id = T2.ParentId;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c051fc/4